# Como saber se o scroll do browser está próximo da altura da div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer com que as divs que estão ocultas ao ficarem na mesma altura (ou próximo) do scroll do browser apareçam (individualmente), como efeito fedeIn.
Alguém pode me ajudar com alguma ideia?

Answer (score 5):

Para capturar o [`scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/), use o:

```
var scrollTop = $('html, body').scrollTop();
```

Para verificar o `top` do elemento em questão, use o [`.offset().top`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), há também há o [`.position().top`](https://api.jquery.com/position/), mas este captura a posição em relação ao elemento pai, ao contrário do anterior, que captura em relação ao documento:

```
$('#box1').offset().top
```

O evento que se pode usar é o `.scroll()`:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
```

### Exemplo:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var scrollTop = $('html, body').scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop >= $('#box1').offset().top){
   $('#box1').css('background', 'red');
  }else{
   $('#box1').css('background', '#ccc');
  }
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
#box1{ background: #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

Em relação ao efeito `fadeIn()`, este é aplicado a elemento com o `display: none` ou seja, ao menos que esteja com o `position` `fixed` ou `absolute` este irá mover os elementos ao aparecer, e dependendo da sua página, pode dar problemas. Mas pode mudar a opacidade com o [.fadeTo()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/). Ficaria algo como isto:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var scrollTop = $('html, body').scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop >= $('#box1').offset().top){
   $('#box1').stop().fadeTo(100, 1);
  }else{
   $('#box1').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
  }
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
#box1{ background: #ccc; opacity: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```